# Unexpected movement behavior combining an Object3D group, PerspectiveCamera and FlyControl

Tags: three.js

In order to write a HUD, I've stuck a camera inside of an Object3D, with the intent of placing HUD elements inside of the same Object3D.

Instead of updating the camera, I now update the HUD, and hopefully all objects in it. However,

- When moving the mouse, the camera seems to revolve around the center of the scene.
- When pressing W, which used to move the camera forward, I now move sideways in front of the center of the scene.

Included are the condensed lines described here:

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
hud = new THREE.Object3D();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...);
hud.add(camera);
scene.add(hud);

control = new THREE.FlyControls(hud, renderer.domElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the HUD Object3D to camera and not the other way around. That should work how one expects.

```
hud = new THREE.Object3D();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...);
camera.add(hud);
scene.add(camera);

control = new THREE.FlyControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: Thanks! I know now that the key is in readding the camera to the scene after adding elements to the camera!